# Why does google rich snippets show: "Item does not support reviews"? Is the the implementation of "@graph" keyword correct?

Tags: html, seo, metadata, json-ld, structured-data

Is the following schema correct?
Should I make any changes?
If I do have to make any changes how should I make them?

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@graph": [
        {
            "@type": "MedicalCondition",
            "associatedAnatomy": {
                "@type": "AnatomicalStructure",
                "name": "Eye"
            },
            "name": "Diabetic retinopathy",
            "signOrSymptom": [
                {
                    "@type": "MedicalSymptom",
                    "name": "Floaters"
                },
                {
                    "@type": "MedicalSymptom",
                    "name": "Dark Spot"
                },
                {
                    "@type": "MedicalSymptom",
                    "name": "Blurred vision"
                },
                {
                    "@type": "MedicalSymptom",
                    "name": "Reduced Night Vision"
                }
            ],
            "typicalTest": [
                {
                    "@type": "MedicalTest",
                    "name": "OCT scan",
                    "description": "An OCT scan is a non-invasive latest advancement in imaging technology. Similar to ultrasound, this diagnostic technique employs light rather than sound waves to achieve higher resolution (5 micron resolution) pictures of the structural layers of the ratina very prcisely.",
                    "usesDevice": "Optical Coherence Tomography (OCT)",
                    "image": "https://www.asianeyehospital.com/images/OCT.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "@type": "MedicalTest",
                    "name": "FFA",
                    "description": "It is a common procedure that is performed to give more information about the blood vessels of the retina. A fluorescein dye is injected in the blood vessel of the arm. Then by specialised magnifying camera quick photographs are taken of your retina.",
                    "usesDevice": "Fundus Fluorescein Angiography (FFA)",
                    "image": "https://www.asianeyehospital.com/images/fundus.jpg"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "@type": "Person",
            "name": "DR. SHRUTIKA KANKARIYA",
            "affiliation": "Asian Eye Hospital",
            "alumniOf": [
                {
                    "@type": "EducationalOrganization",
                    "name": "Seth GS medical college"
                },
                {
                    "@type": "EducationalOrganization",
                    "name": "KEM hospital, Mumbai"
                },
                {
                    "@type": "EducationalOrganization",
                    "name": "Sankara Netralaya ,Chennai"
                }
            ],
            "hasCredential": [
                {
                    "@type": "EducationalOccupationalCredential",
                    "name": "MBBS"
                },
                {
                    "@type": "EducationalOccupationalCredential",
                    "name": "DNB"
                },
                {
                    "@type": "EducationalOccupationalCredential",
                    "name": "FICO"
                }
            ],
            "description": "Dr. Shrutika Junagade Kankariya, (MBBS, DNB, FICO, Fellow Retina and Diabetes Eye Disease) is an advanced medical retina, diabetic eye disease and cataract expert. She completed her medical college training from prestigious and one of the best medical college in India, Seth GS medical college and KEM hospital, Mumbai. She completed her ophthalmic education at one of the finest eye institute in Asia; Sankara Netralaya ,Chennai, under the aegis of diplomat of the national board (DNB). She has obtained FICO UK (Fellow international council of ophthalmology, united kingdom. Thereafter she underwent advanced fellowship in retinal disorders at sankara netralaya Chennai (Busiest center catering to referrals for retinal disorders from all over Asia)."
        },
        {
            "@type": "Review",
            "author": "Mrs India and actor, model Poonam Shende",
            "reviewBody": "Its a dream come true for me to have perfect vision without glasses! Thank you Dr Kankariya for your magic :)",
            "itemReviewed": {
                "@type": "Thing",
                "name": "Asian Eye Hospital"
            },
            "reviewRating": {
                "@type": "Rating",
                "ratingValue": 5,
                "worstRating": 1,
                "bestRating": 5
            }
        },
        {
            "@type": "Review",
            "author": "Bollywood Actress Sonalee Kulkarni",
            "reviewBody": "My entire family has got freedom from glasses at Asian Eye Hospital. Dr Kankariya has magical hands",
            "itemReviewed": {
                "@type": "Thing",
                "name": "Asian Eye Hospital"
            },
            "reviewRating": {
                "@type": "Rating",
                "ratingValue": 5,
                "worstRating": 1,
                "bestRating": 5
            }
        },
        {
            "@type": "Review",
            "author": "Professor Dr Ioannis Pallikaris",
            "reviewBody": "Dr Vardhaman Kankariya is a globally renowned expert and I am proud to be his mentor. If I need eye surgery I will come to Dr Kankariya myself.",
            "itemReviewed": {
                "@type": "Thing",
                "name": "Asian Eye Hospital"
            },
            "reviewRating": {
                "@type": "Rating",
                "ratingValue": 5,
                "worstRating": 1,
                "bestRating": 5
            }
        },
        {
            "@type": "Review",
            "author": "Hon. Ahmed Adeeb Former Vice President of Maldives",
            "reviewBody": "Dr Kankariya is truly an expert. I was referred to Asian Eye from Maldives for my eye treatment and I am very happy",
            "itemReviewed": {
                "@type": "Thing",
                "name": "Asian Eye Hospital"
            },
            "reviewRating": {
                "@type": "Rating",
                "ratingValue": 5,
                "worstRating": 1,
                "bestRating": 5
            }
        },
        {
            "@type": "Review",
            "author": "Honourable Former President of India, Smt Pratibhatai Patil",
            "reviewBody": "I congratulate Dr Kankariya to have returned back to India and provide expertise to our Indian patients. Asian Eye Hospital is a boon for Pune",
            "itemReviewed": {
                "@type": "Thing",
                "name": "Asian Eye Hospital"
            },
            "reviewRating": {
                "@type": "Rating",
                "ratingValue": 5,
                "worstRating": 1,
                "bestRating": 5
            }
        },
        {
            "@type": "VideoObject",
            "position": 1,
            "name": "Couple from Netherlands Undergo Successful Spectacle Removal Laser | Dr Kankariya | Pune",
            "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g6Ktd62WV6g",
            "thumbnailUrl": [
                "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/g6Ktd62WV6g/maxresdefault.jpg"
            ],
            "uploadDate": "2018-10-02",
            "duration": "PT0M42S",
            "contentUrl": "",
            "embedUrl": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/g6Ktd62WV6g",
            "interactionStatistic": {
                "@type": "InteractionCounter",
                "interactionType": {
                    "@type": "http://schema.org/WatchAction"
                },
                "userInteractionCount": 567
            }
        },
        {
            "@type": "VideoObject",
            "position": 2,
            "name": "Dr Shrutika Kankariya Zee TV Interview | Marathi | Cataract & Diabetes Eye Diseases | Asian Eye Pune",
            "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kuRO8JRPGO8",
            "thumbnailUrl": [
                "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kuRO8JRPGO8/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEbCKgBEF5IVfKriqkDDggBFQAAiEIYAXABwAEG\u0026rs=AOn4CLC28IhXMx4-veeVcXO7C4au3X9pBA"
            ],
            "uploadDate": "2017-02-02",
            "duration": "PT22M421S",
            "contentUrl": "",
            "embedUrl": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/kuRO8JRPGO8",
            "interactionStatistic": {
                "@type": "InteractionCounter",
                "interactionType": {
                    "@type": "http://schema.org/WatchAction"
                },
                "userInteractionCount": 8907
            }
        },
        {
            "@type": "VideoObject",
            "position": 3,
            "name": "Padmavibhushan Dr K H Sancheti speaking about Dr Vardhaman Kankariya and Asian Eye Hospital, Pune",
            "url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9l3M5-S5g4w",
            "thumbnailUrl": [
                "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/9l3M5-S5g4w/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEbCKgBEF5IVfKriqkDDggBFQAAiEIYAXABwAEG\u0026rs=AOn4CLDap5Qy_wNlTZV7rwRgpfx92ii4cQ%22,"
            ],
            "uploadDate": "2018-11-14",
            "duration": "PT6M12S",
            "contentUrl": "",
            "embedUrl": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/9l3M5-S5g4w",
            "interactionStatistic": {
                "@type": "InteractionCounter",
                "interactionType": {
                    "@type": "http://schema.org/WatchAction"
                },
                "userInteractionCount": 1432
            }
        }
    ]
}
</script>
```

For the above schema:
Why does the google rich snippets tool show:
"Item Does Not Support Reviews"

The following part is highlighted in red.

Also, is my implementation of @graph keyword correct?

```
@type": "Review",
            "author": "Professor Dr Ioannis Pallikaris",
            "reviewBody": "Dr Vardhaman Kankariya is a globally renowned expert and I am proud to be his mentor. If I need eye surgery I will come to Dr Kankariya myself.",
            "itemReviewed": {
                "@type": "Thing",
                "name": "Asian Eye Hospital"
            },
            "reviewRating": {
                "@type": "Rating",
                "ratingValue": 5,
                "worstRating": 1,
                "bestRating": 5
            }
```

How do I fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rich Snippets Test tool is focused on structured data that can cause rich snippets. Your review is of a "Thing". Here's a list of the types that Google may show reviews for:

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/review-snippet